# Sliding экранов

Tags: android, java

Почитал несколько статей про `sliding` экранов и везде была их реализация в одном `Activity` (с помощью анимации, `ViewPager`, `ViewFlipper`). Возник вопрос, можно ли сделать `sliding` экранов с передачей данных между `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то тебе поможет метод активити - overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim). Этот метод подставляет кастомную(свою) анимацию для переходов между активити. С помощью него я добавлял анимацию в приложение как в айфоне при переходах на новый экран.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что это то что нужно [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/118482/)